# Index of letter removed to make string palindrome

Tags: python, programming-challenge, palindrome

This code finds the index in the string and removes the one which will make the string a palindrome. If the string is already a palindrome, it should return -1.

This code works correct, but I am looking for a better implementation of it. [Here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/palindrome-index) is the problem description.

```
def palindrome(string):
    return string == string[::-1]

def palindrome_index(string, start, end):
    while start < end:
        if string[start] == string[end]:
            start, end = start+1, end-1
            continue
        if palindrome(string[start:end]): return end
        return start
    return -1
N = input()
strings = [str(raw_input()) for _ in range(N)]
for string in strings:
    print palindrome_index(string, 0, len(string)-1)
```

Can this be written shorter?  The size of input strings can be as large as 10<sup>5</sup>, hence a recursive approach won't work.

Comment: Again, could you please clarify the specification for this code? Do you have e.g. a problem description you could share? Are there passing and failing test cases we can run?

Comment: [Links can rot. Please include a summary of the challenge in your question.](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1993/41243)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Flow

The `continue` and `return`s inside the while loop make me feel the loop is doing too much.  I would say that the loop should be for moving `start` and `end` and then put the logic outside of it:

```
while ( start < end and string[start] == string[end] ):
    start, end = start + 1, end - 1

# now figure out the result
```

### Result

The problem states that all strings that are not already palindromes are only off by one character.

Our loop moved `start` and `end` such that if `start == end`, then the string is a palindrome.  It has also moved these indices such that if the string is not a palindrome, one of them is 'pointing' to the character that needs to be removed.

To figure out which index is correct, I chose to compare the character pointed to by `start` to the character pointed to by `end - 1`.

```
if ( start == end ):
    return -1
elif ( string[ start ] == string[ end - 1 ] ):
    return end
else:
    return start
```

### Palindrome Function

You don't need this function at all because we know that if the string is not a palindrome, it is only off by one character.  We were able to figure out the index of this character just by moving `start` and `end`

Anyway, since the function returns a boolean, it should be named `isPalindrome`

Comment: string[ start ] == string[ end - 1 ] does not cover all the test cases, you need to out another check like
string[start+1] == string[end-2]
Take 'abaab' for example.